# Test lambda function with spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, mocking, spock

```java
@CustomLog
@Data
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonalizationTasks {
    
    private final CmdUtils cmdUtils;

    @Value("${cmd.task-defaults.personalization-service-type}")
    private String version;

    @ExternalTaskSubscription(topicName = "personalization")
    @Bean
    public ExternalTaskHandler personalization() {
        return (task, taskService) -> {
            Long appId = task.getVariable("appId");        
            //other codes
            taskService.complete(task);       
        };
    }
}
```

When I try to test this method, my test doesn't run this return body. How can I test it?

***Edit by kriegaex:*** Probably the OP uses Camunda interface [`ExternalTaskHandler`](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.16/org/camunda/bpm/client/task/ExternalTaskHandler.html).

Comment: Do you need to test that TestExtTask returns lambda, or you need to test the body of the lambda?

Comment: the body of the lambda

Comment: @AyshanRzayeva, please give your questions some more love in the future. I improved code formatting and syntax highlighting for you and also added a link to the Camunda class you are using. Please also edit the question further and refine it, converting it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so everybody can reproduce your problem. We need a full minimal application and a full test. SO is a Q/A platform, not for asking others to do your job for you but for showing what code you have and asking concrete, answerable questions about how to fix it.

Comment: I would suggest do extract the lambda into a proper class. Production code should not live in configuration classes, as that makes it harder to test. Furthermore, the injected fields are not used in the lambda so why are they present in the config class? Also without the actual test code we don't know what you are doing wrong on that side.

Answer (score 0):

As ExternalTaskHandler is a lambda, it has the `execute​` method, so you need to call it with provided arguments, so body of the lambda will be executed, something like that:

```
@Inject
private ExternalTaskHandler handler;

@Test
void shouldExecuteTask() {
    ExternalTask externalTask = mock(ExternalTask.class);
    ExternalTaskService externalTaskService = mock(ExternalTaskService.class);

    hanler.execute(externalTask, externalTaskService);
    verify(externalTaskService).complete(externalTask);
}
```

Comment: `ExternalTaskService externalTaskService 
 ExternalTask externalTask
@InjectMocks
ExternalTaskHandler externalTaskHandler
ExtTasks extTasks

    void setup() {       
        externalTask = Mock()
        externalTaskService = Mock()
        extTasks= new ExtTasks ()
 }

    def "TestExtTask"() {
        given:      
        when:
        externalTaskHandler.execute(externalTask, externalTaskService)
        extTasks.testExtTask()
        then:
        1 * externalTask.getVariable(_ as String) >> "123"
    }`

it doesnt work

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: null, I have to write extTasks.testExtTask.execute(task, taskHandler) (testExtTask is in extTasks class). Problem was fixed thank you